# Neo4J webadmin with password protection

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to have password protection on `localhost:7474/webadmin`? It is better if we put a htaccess and htpasswd files in the folder but I cannot find the folder webadmin lies. I believe if I find the path, I can protect it with password. Anyone who knows the folder path? The documentation does not say about it.

additional information: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and neo4j version is 1.8.

Comment: The link in Michael's response should go here: [authentication-extension](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension)

Answer (score 4):

You can either use an apache proxy in front of Neo4j, [see the manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/security-server.html)

or look into something like the [authentication-extension](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension) which supplies basic-auth.

Comment: Quick question: I believe you wrote the plugin. Is it just for the webadmin interface or when I use the plugin, do I also set the username and password combination in my code too?

Comment: Or if you want authentication using NGINX as proxy, [you can look here](http://joewhite86.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/secure-neo4j-webadmin-using-http-auth-and-ssl/)